# Can't get output from SQL Server Compact 

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have the following code behind a button in Visual Studio 2010

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCeConnection Con = new SqlCeConnection();

    Con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = 'DB.sdf';" + "Password='my Password';";

    SqlCeCommand Query = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Password FROM Admin");

    try        
    {
       Con.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    SqlCeDataReader Reader=Query.ExecuteReader();
    MessageBox.Show(Reader["Password"].ToString());
}
```

It works fine execute and no exception in connection but when I press the button it raises an exception saying

> Error: Execute Reader Connection Property Has Not Been Initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not associating your command with your connection - try this:

```
SqlCeConnection Con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = 'AlviMBRental.sdf';Password='my Password';";

SqlCeCommand Query = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Password FROM Admin", Con);  //   <== specify "Con" here!
```

Otherwise, your `SqlCeCommand` has no connection to work with....

Answer (score 2):

<sub>I'm not going to attempt to comment on database access code in a UI event handler, it will detract from the answer too much. All I will say is, try not to do it.</sub>

**You haven't associated the connection with the command**, either in the [command constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8xbzx6zd%28v=vs.100%29) or the relevant [`Connection` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.connection%28v=vs.100%29).

---

I would re-write the entire method to the following to cut out the dangerous try-catch (catching everything, very bad practice) and to utilise the fact `using` statements also handle object disposal for you:

```
string password = null;

using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = 'AlviMBRental.sdf'; Password='my Password';"))
using (var comm = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Password FROM Admin", conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        password = (string)reader["Password"];

    } // Dispose reader

    // Alternatively, if the resultset is single column and single row, you can do:
    var passwordScalar = (string)comm.ExecuteScalar();

} // Dispose command, close / dispose connection.

MessageBox.Show(password ?? "No password found.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connectionString = "Data Source='AlviMBRental.sdf';Password='my Password';";
    using (var con = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Password FROM Admin";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())        
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(reader["Password"].ToString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you have associated the connection with the command object. Also make sure you have wrapped IDisposable objects in `using` statements as shown in my example.